# Shiny App - Build an interactive help for the user

Tags: r, shiny

I'm learning (mostly for fun) shiny and i'm building a dashboard with some tabular data and ggplot graphs.

I'd like to know if there's a possibility to implement a sort of interactive help for the app users, i.e the user pass its mouse pointer on a certain graph and it will pop up a brief description of the plot. When the user move the mouse pointer away the brief description should disappear.

I 've just discovered `helpText()` function but obviously is far away from what I'd like to implement.

I may add that I don't know any JS and I know basics (very basics) of html and css.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is wonderful `rintrojs` package which will do what you want, here is small example:

```
library(rintrojs)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  introjsUI(),
  actionButton("help", "About this Page"),
  sidebarPanel(
    introBox(sliderInput("Slider", "Slider",min = 1, max = 10, value = 5,step = 1),data.step = 1,data.intro = "This is slider its doing xyz"),
    introBox(actionButton("Button","Button"),data.step = 2,data.intro = "This is Button its doing other things"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$help,introjs(session, options = list("showBullets"="false", "showProgress"="true", "showStepNumbers"="false","nextLabel"="Next","prevLabel"="Prev","skipLabel"="Skip")))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.. I don't know why I didn't see it.